# Will AWS RDS Multi-AZ failover cause unexpected data transfer costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

According to the Amazon [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html), I should setup my RDS database with multiple availability zones (multi-AZ) for high availability and automatic failover. However data transfer between EC2 and RDS within the same availability zone is free whereas data transfer between zones is not (see [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)). So if I setup my webserver on an EC2 instance in the same AZ as my database server - to get the zero data transfer costs, and the database server then fails and automatically failovers to a different AZ, will Amazon suddenly start charging me data transfer costs?

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to minimise this data transfer cost, or is it just luck if you end up running in the same AZ or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really like Multi-AZ.  You are worried about the data transfer costs but these tend to be minimal. I normally pay cents.  With Multi-AZ the real cost is that you pay about 75% more to have the failover server on standby... however, the failover is still slow, taking several minutes, so you will get an outage.  You would have thought if you're paying so much that the failover procedure would take seconds, but it doesn't.

The failover server will not be in the same AZ - this defeats the whole point. And, theoretically, the outage should be a few hours, so the inter-AZ data transfers will be short-lived.

Another point is that if you have, say, your web servers and RDS in AZ us-east-1b, and this AZ goes down, then it's pretty useless having an RDS failover because your web servers are down!

Given all this, I go with "assume robust". This means I expect AWS to be 99.9% and if something happens (which never has to me), it will be short lived and something to live with.  OR you can almost double your costs and MAYBE it will work if there is an outage.

This does not apply, of course, to mega-sites with servers in many zones, proper load balancing, cluster databases etc. But I'm pretty sure they don't use RDS Multi-AZ!